# Boolean expression to determine what website I am on

Tags: java, xpath, webdriver

I want to create a Boolean that tells me true if I am on www.google.com and I tried using some code that failed because I can't do it on strings. I need to make conditional logic where the program runs a specific set of code if it's on a staging and a different set if it's on a production environment. Here's some code to help the process along.

```
boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.Xpath"...").size() == 0; //I want this to look for the website 

if(isPresent) //If it's on the website I want then this else that code. 
{
driver.findElement(by.xpath("...").click();
}
else
{
Assert.assertTrue(enterPledge.Whatevert));
}
```

Comment: `driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("www.google.com")`, perhaps?

Comment: Like this? boolean isPresent = driverdriver.getCurrentUrl().contains("www.google.com")